# rails nested attributes destroy not working on patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes, destroy

On an update of my agreement model, i might need to update 1 to many attachments, this could involve deleting an attachment. I have set up rails nested attributes on the model and everything seems to be working for it, such as adding and updating. but i can't seem to get deleting working.

I have read the docs and have added all the necessary bits of code to enable this feature. but nothing seems to be sticking.

Using Rails 5.0.7.1 and ruby 2.4.2

```
here is my agreement model 

  has_many :attachments,
           :class_name => 'Attachment',
           :foreign_key => 'attachable_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
```

```
here is the relevant controller code

  def update
    agreement = Contract::Agreement.find(params[:id])

    if agreement.update_attributes(agreement_params)
      render json: agreement, serializer: Contract::Agreement::Agreement
    else
      render json: {}, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

def agreement_params
    byebug
    unless params[:agreement][:attachments].blank?

      params[:agreement][:attachments_attributes] = params[:agreement][:attachments].map { |attachment|

        new_attachment = {}

        attachment.each do |key, value|
          new_attachment[:key] = value
        end
      }
      params[:agreement].delete :attachments
    end

    # byebug

    unless params[:agreement][:services].blank?
      params[:agreement][:services_attributes] = params[:agreement][:services]
      params[:agreement].delete :services
    end

    params.require(:agreement).permit(
      :status,
      :start_date,
      :end_date,
      :description,
      :parent,
      :level_id,
      :term_id,
      :service_provider_id,
      attachments_attributes: [
        :id,
        :file,
        :file_name,
        :file_size,
        :file_type,
        :attachable_type,
        :attachable_id,
        :_destroy
      ],
      services_attributes: [
        :id,
        :currency,
        :price,
        :facguid,
        :service_type_id,
        :agreement_id
      ]
    )
  end
```

```
and here is the test

it 'successfully deletes attachments', :attachments_testes => true do
        agreement = FactoryBot.create(:contract_agreement)

        attachment = FactoryBot.create(:agreement_attachment)
        attachment.attachable_id = agreement.id
        attachment.save

        expect(Attachment.count).to eq(1)

        agreement_attachments = [{id: attachment.id, _destroy: '1'}]
        patch :update, params: {id: agreement.id, agreement: {
            status: 'X',
            attachments: agreement_attachments
        }
        }
        agreement_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

        expect(response).to be_success
        expect(agreement_response['status']).to eq('X')
        byebug
        expect(Attachment.count).to eq(0)
      end
```

obviously, the attachment should be deleted from my db. WHen i do my initial check on attachments in the middle of test i do have 1 attachment in the db and it is linked to the agreement. But in the last expect after the response successfully comes back everything is updated, but the attachment is still there, as if it ignored the _destroy.

Answer (score 0):

In your test you have:

```rb
params: { id: agreement.id, 
         agreement: { status: 'X', 
                      attachments: agreement_attachments } 
        }
```

Shouldn't it be:

```rb
params: { id: agreement.id, 
          agreement: { status: 'X',
                       attachments_attributes: agreement_attachments }
        }
```